# ContentScript.js in chrome extension , is not listening for "message" from background.js

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, content-script

I am simply sending this message from `background` to `contentScript` ,
The content is supposed to listen for this message and execute the function .

My contentScript.js :

```
function clickButton() {
  const sendButton = document.querySelector('span[data-testid="send"]');
  if (sendButton) {
    console.log("Button Clicked");
    sendButton.click();
    // Communicate back to the background script or popup
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "buttonClicked" });
  }
}

// Execute the clickButton function when a message is received
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "clickButton") {
    console.log("Content Script HIT") ;
    clickButton();
  }
});
```

background.js :

```
 chrome.tabs.create({ url: url }, function (tab){
    
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function listener(tabId, changeInfo) {
      if (tabId === tab.id && changeInfo.status === "complete") {

         console.log('TAB CREATED') ; 
       
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "clickButton" }, function (response) {
          console.log('Response from ContentScript', response);
          sendResponse({ success: true });
        });
        

        }
      });
    })
```

The official chrome documentation also doesn't seem to help more than what I already did

`https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/`

Comment: 1) Your `content_scripts` declaration in manifest.json may have incorrect `matches` that doesn't cover the `url` you open. 2) Open devtools in the created tab and check the console for errors. 3) Consider using chrome.scripting.executeScript instead of onUpdated + sendMessage.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer for those , struggling with the same issue :

The problem was with my ***manifest.json*** , I was missing the following field . It indicates the host/platform where your ***contentScript.js*** should be executed :

```
 "content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["https://anyurl.com"],
  "js": ["contentScript.js"]
}
```

]

Also , for executing contentScript on all web pages , you can use :

```
"matches": ["<all_urls">]
```